# for loop - non over lapping block sizes

Tags: julia

I am working a problem where I am running calculations over varying block widths, lets say blocks of 8,16,32.... 1024

So lets see how the blocks would look like for widths of 8:

```
size_8 = collect(1:8:1024)

julia> print(size_8)
[1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89, 97, 105, 113, 121, 129, 137, 145, 153, 161, 169, 177,
 185, 193, 201, 209, 217, 225, 233, 241, 249, 257, 265, 273, 281, 289, 297, 305, 313, 321, 329, 337,
 345, 353, 361, 369, 377, 385, 393, 401, 409, 417, 425, 433, 441, 449, 457, 465, 473, 481, 489, 497,
 505, 513, 521, 529, 537, 545, 553, 561, 569, 577, 585, 593, 601, 609, 617, 625, 633, 641, 649, 657,
 665, 673, 681, 689, 697, 705, 713, 721, 729, 737, 745, 753, 761, 769, 777, 785, 793, 801, 809, 817,
 825, 833, 841, 849, 857, 865, 873, 881, 889, 897, 905, 913, 921, 929, 937, 945, 953, 961, 969, 977,
 985, 993, 1001, 1009, 1017]
```

So the first block is 1:9, the second is 9:17, the third 17:25 so on and so forth.

Next I wish to place these block widths in a for loop using the i iterator. I do not wish to hard code like `size_8[i]:size_8[i]+8` This is because I wish to loop through each value of `n, 8,16,32.... 1024` I do not want to code a whole bunch of size_8, size_16, size_32 .... size_1024 vectors. I would rather loop through each block size value of n.

If we take a rolling loop we can do:

```
n=8 # set width of rolling window
for i = n:size(something,1) 
out[i] = mean(something[i-n+1:i] 
end
```

this is a window width of `8`, this is for over lapping block sizes for increasing `i (i+1)` and as i'm about to describe, need to increase `i` by `8` each time:

So now in the above problem I need to increase `i` by 8 each time vs 1 (which i now realize might not be possible) starting from position `1` and also increase the upper window by `8` each time so that we have:

do something, say mean on `1:9 range, 9:17 range, 17:25` .... so on and so forth - non over lapping blocks.

Anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish without hard coding the ranges in vectors and using the `i` iterators only? I have tried to code the hard coded blocks but its too restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured i could make a dynamic block_size within the loop itself:

```
block_size = [8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]

 for i in 1:length(block_size)
    size = collect(1:block_size[i]:length(something))
    print(size)
    end
```

Now I can for any n:

```
size[i]:size[i]+n
```